# Set image as wallpaper using intent like gallery app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-wallpaper

I have managed to find the code to set an image as wallpaper using intent. But the dialog is showing me 2 more options "Contact photo" and "Wallpaper"

[image]

So is there any option to just show the first 3 options only? like what happens inside the gallery app when you click set as wallpaper it shows you only 3 options. "Home and lock screens", "Home screen", and "Lock screen"

Comment: I think this very much depends on the android version, not something we alter. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @Letsintegreat I think that too! But what is confusing to me how the gallery app can show only these 3 options on  the same phone with the same android version